# C++17 Limit type of fold expression for initialization of a template-class

Tags: c++, constructor, variadic-templates, aggregate-initialization, fold-expression

I basically try to write my own game engine for practice and personal use (I know, it's a nearly impossible task, but as I said, it's mostly for learning new things).

Currently, I'm working on my math library (mainly vectors and matrices) and I came across an interesting, but mostly, aesthetic problem.

### **The following pseudo-code is given:**

```
template <uint8 size>
struct TVector {
    float elements[size];
};
```

Now I want to be able to construct the struct with the required amount of floats as parameters:

```
TVector<3> vec0(1.0f, 2.5f, -4.0f); 
TVector<2> vec1(3.0f, -2.0f);

TVector<3> vec2(2.0f, 2.2f); // Error: arg missing 
TVector<2> vec3(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f) // Error: too many args
```

Since the size of array is given by the template parameter, I struggled with declaring a fitting constructor for the struct. My ultimate goal would be something like this:

```
// This is pseudo-ideal-code
TVector(size * (float value)); // Create a constructor with number of size 
                               // parameters, which are all floats
```

Of course, this is non-logical syntax, but the closest thing I achieved in that manner was with *C++17 fold expressions*:

```
template<typename... Args>
    TVector(Args... values) {
        static_assert(sizeof...(values) <= size, "Too many args");
        uint8 i = 0;
        (... , void(elements[i++] = values));
    }
```

It works perfectly fine in sense of filling the array and (I guess) is not much overhead, but it is also error-prone for the programmer who uses this struct, since it gives no direct indication of **how many** arguments the constructor takes in.

Furthermore, it does not specify **which type** of the arguments should be and this is my biggest problem here.

### **Why is it a problem if it works?**

Imagine having the following struct, which uses the TVector struct:

```
template <const uint8 rows, const uint8 columns>
struct TMatrix {
    // elements[-columns-][-rows-]; 
    TVector<rows> elements[columns];
}
```

Given, that the constructor is similar to the fold expression of the vector struct,
I want to be able to construct the matrix with the accordingly sized vectors or brace initialization.

1. The aggregate initialization does not work.

   ```
   TVector<2> vec(1.0f, 3.0f);
   TMatrix<2, 2> mat0(vec, vec); // Works
   TMatrix<2, 2> mat1(vec, {0.2f, -4.2f}); // Error
   // Does not compile, because the Type is not clear
   ```
2. It does not show an error until compilation when given the wrong parameters 
   (like a vector with a wrong size, that would not fit as column of the matrix).
3. The source of the error is not always clear.

### **TL;DR: Now finally to my real question here:**

Is there a way to limit the type of a fold expression, ultimately not using templates at all and solving my 3 problems given above?

I imagine something like:

```
TVector(float... values) { 
// Maybe even specify the size of the pack with the size given in the struct template
    uint8 i = 0;
    (... , void(elements[i++] = values));
}
```

And:

```
TMatrix(const TVector<rows>&... values) {
    uint8 i = 0;
    (..., void(elements[i++] = values));
}
```

Of course, I am being very picky here and this is mostly an aesthetic problem, but I think it is an important design decision, which could really improve code usability.

---

*Thank you for reading this and helping me with my first question here :)*

Comment: You could create deduction guide with enable if if all of the types are not convertible to doubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after diving into template metaprogramming and trying out things, I came across some solutions (all with their own little problems).

### std::initializer_list:

**Pros:**

- Easy to implement:

  ```
  // Constructors:
  TVector(std::initalizer_list<float> values);
  TMatrix(std::initalizer_list<TVector<rows>> values);
  ```
- Brace initialization:

  ```
  TVector<3>    vec { 1.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f };
  TMatrix<3, 3> mat { vec, { 3.0f, 4.0f, 1.0f }, vec };
  ```

**Cons:**

- Copy overhead
- Values can't be moved
- Does not specify the allowed number of parameters
- I suggest Andrzej's C++ Blog on that topic: [The cost of std::initializer_list](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/the-cost-of-stdinitializer_list/)

---

### std::array

**Pros:**

- Easy to implement:

  ```
  // Constructors:
  TVector(std::array<float, size>&& values);
  TMatrix(std::aray<TVector<rows>, columns>&& values);
  ```
- Movable if the objects in the array are movable

**Cons:**

- Brace initialization is extremely ugly

  ```
  TVector<3>    vec { { 1.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f } };
  TMatrix<3, 3> mat { vec, TVector<3>{ { 3.0f, 4.0f, 1.0f } }, vec };
  ```

---

### Fold expression - My prefered solution

**Pros:**

- No overhead
- Movable
- Uses uniform initialization

  ```
  TVector<3>    vec { 1.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f };
  TMatrix<3, 3> mat { vec, TVector<3>{ 3.0f, 4.0f, 1.0f }, vec };
  ```
- Can be specified for the need of the constructor

**Cons:**

- Hard to implement and to specify
- Does not allow nested braces without specifying the type (as far as I can tell)

  ```
  // Constructors:
  template<typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<
      is_pack_convertible<float, Args...>::value && 
      is_pack_size_of<columns, Args...>::value, bool> = false >
  TVector(std::array<float, size>&& values);

  template<typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<
      is_pack_convertible<Vector<rows>, Args...>::value && 
      is_pack_size_of<columns, Args...>::value, bool> = false >
  TMatrix(std::aray<TVector<rows>, columns>&& values);
  ```

### is_pack_convertible / is_pack_size_of

```
// Declaration - checks if all types of a pack are convertible to one type
template <typename To, typename... Pack> struct is_pack_convertible;
// End of pack case
template <typename To> struct is_pack_convertible<To> : std::true_type {};
// Recursive bool &&
template <typename To, typename From, typename... Pack>
struct is_pack_convertible<To, From, Pack...> {
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_convertible<From, To>::value
        && is_pack_convertible<To, Pack...>::value;
};

// Declaration - checks if the pack is equal to a certain size
template <size_t size, typename... Pack> struct is_pack_size_of;
// End of pack: size is equal
template <> struct is_pack_size_of<0> : std::true_type {};
// End of pack: size is not equal
template <size_t remainder> struct is_pack_size_of<remainder> : std::false_type {};
// Count down size for every element in pack
template <size_t size, typename Arg, typename... Pack> 
struct is_pack_size_of<size, Arg, Pack...> {
    static constexpr bool value = is_pack_size_of<size - 1, Pack...>::value;
};
```

---

I hope this helps other people and gives a brief overview of the options when initializing generic classes.

Answer (score 3):

With indirection, you may do something like:

```
template <typename Seq> struct TVectorImpl;

template <std::size_t, typename T> using force_type = T;

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct TVectorImpl<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    TVectorImpl(force_type<Is, float>... args) : elements{args...} {}

    float elements[sizeof...(Is)];
};

template <std::size_t size>
using TVector = TVectorImpl<decltype(std::make_index_sequence<size>())>;
```

That avoids to have also template method (so construct as `{2.4, 5}` works).

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3acbffa302eb7bd6)

Note that it is in C++14 (and `index_sequence` can be done in C++11).